# Could the government legally create an election in which only some people could vote?

Tags: democracy, supreme-court, referendum

I was considering that if I were in some lawmaking position I would consider advocating that abortion rights should be voted on by females and the result of that election would become law.

On philosophical and ethical grounds it makes sense to me. Whereas on most issues it would seem wrong to only allow a special interest group to vote, because the issue affects everyone in society, it does also seem like there are sometimes social phenomena that are only relevant to a specific class of human. Laws are generally meant to prohibit immoral actions as well as improve society out of a collective obligation for everyone to equally contribute to that end. It makes sense that if a law only would affect the quality of life of a specific group, with limited ramifications for people outside that group; and since democracy is basically just meant to be a census, an average, of what people want for themselves, where the majority rules; that you could create sub-group specific elections. For example, residents of one state cannot vote in the elections of a different state, I believe.

Is it legally possible to create a group-specific vote? If lawmakers proposed a referendum, sort of like Brexit, with the clause that only women would vote, and that the result would become enacted, could lawmakers or citizens vote such a referendum into existence, or would it be struck down as unconstitutional?

Comment: People under voting age would like to point out this already happens.

Comment: What country is this question about? If you are talking about the United States, then you would also need to say what state you are talking about, because only states have referendums on laws and the constitutional court ruled a while ago that abortion is a state issue.

Comment: Wouldn't it then be not a democracy anymore by definition?

Comment: What a brilliant idea that in no way could lead to "Whites-only" elections.

Comment: The major issue with this type of idea, though it may seem sensible on the surface, is that the people left out of a vote will usually insist that the results will affect them. And how do you determine whether they are right or not? A...vote? Or does some nominally unbiased group (like the totally fair US Supreme Court) decide it?

Comment: Before we get more non-answers stating "depends on where and on the specific laws at that place", I am closing the question. Please add a tag which states the jurisdiction. Then we can reopen it.

Comment: Just look at one of the *accepted* versions of this idea: people only voting on laws for their own countries. A lot of people  would claim that pollution laws in the US, China, India and Russia really *do* affect people in Tuvalu, for instance. So even in the clear-cut instances of this, limiting voting only to people who are supposed to be directly affected can have consequences.

Comment: @Philipp the supreme court did not rule that abortion is a state issue.  It ruled that there is no federal right to abortion to be found in the (implicit) federal right of privacy.  That doesn't preclude the federal government from passing laws on abortion.  It doesn't even preclude a court from finding a right to abortion in some other federal right.

Comment: Assuming that the OP meant this to be a question based on the United States, the specific scenario is unconstitutional.  Per the 19th amendment, which grant women the right to vote "The right of citizens of the United States to vote shall not be denied or abridged by the United States or by any State on account of sex." Denying men the right to vote on Abortion would is an abridgement of the right to vote based on sex.  That said, in the U.S. unless it is explicitly restricted in the Constitution, individual states can restrict voting rights as they see fit.

Answer (score 4):

The question is not really possible to answer as asked. This is mainly because you have given no information which country's legal system you are talking about. "Would it be struck down as unconstitutional?" is a question that makes sense in those countries where "striking something down as unconstitutional" is a thing that exists. That is true e.g. of the United States, France, Germany, Austria, Ireland, but it is not true e.g. of the United Kingdom, where Acts of Parliament cannot be struck down as unconstitutional (mainly because there is no fixed written constitution). So in the UK, Parliament could pass legislation for a referendum with any franchise it wanted.

In most liberal democracies that do have a concept of constitutional rights that must be respected by ordinary legislation, one of them is usually something like "equality under the law". It is likely that the courts would rule that your idea violates that. However, if you are talking about completely hypothetical legal systems, then of course anything you can imagine is possible.

Comment: UK Acts of Parliament cannot be struck down because Parliament is absolutely supreme, not mainly because the constitution is 'unwritten'.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Part of a democracy is to decide who can vote. Can people in prison vote, age-restriction etc.

Usually different elections are regulated by specific laws. E.g. a vote for mayor could maybe include permanent residency, whereas a vote for leader would require a nationality. Or that you both live in the country and are a national etc.